# Corregir REGEX para separar texto con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estoy tratando de validar separacion de espacios de un texto en python con REGEX, ejemplo: `HELLOWorld`, resultado debe ser: `HELLO World`, ejem: **AlejandroHurtado**, el resultado debe ser: **Alejandro Hurtado**

```
import re
s = 'HELLOWorld'
print(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+|[a-z]+', s))
```

El resultado está cercano a lo que quiero, sin embargo la **W** se coló en el primer texto.

```
['HELLOW', 'orld']
```

Sin embargo no me funciona para casos como el texto: **AlejandroHurtado**, resultado esperado: **Alejandro Hurtado**. El código actual me arroja un resultado `['A', 'lejandro', 'H', 'urtado']`, cómo corregir este caso?. Gracias

Comment: Tiene que ser con regex?

Comment: Puede ser tambien con alguna otra forma, la cosas que funcione para ambos casos de texto.

Comment: Algo como `([A-Za-z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)` te sirve?

Comment: @Alfabravo, funciona estimado, quiza puedes poner como respuesta, gracias

Comment: Hecho! Me alegra que sirviera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que deberías revisar N carácteres en el grupo 1 y luego, un carácter mayúscula y N en minúscula como segundo grupo

```
([A-Za-z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)
```

PD. Yo siempre pruebo las expresiones regulares en https://regexr.com/, es bien ilustrativo sobre cómo aplican las expresiones sobre el texto de prueba que definas

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ilustración @Alfabravo